# C# web application razor page - How to overcome IndexOutOfRange exception when editing a collection?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I'm getting started with Razor pages and I have the following problem:

I have this model

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I'm binding it like this on the `Edit.cshtml.cs`

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

And in my `Edit.cshtml` I use it this way

```
@for (byte i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].OrderItemId" />
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Item" />
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Price">
}
```

My loop has to be always from 0 to 5, but the `OrderItems` collection can have even less than 6 items in it.

Now, this works fine in the `New.cshtml` page where the `Order` is a new object and the `OrderItems` is empty. But when I'm trying to edit an existing record I'm getting an error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Is there a way to overcome this error without having to manually fill in the `OrderItems` collection to match the loop's length?

Comment: *"this works fine [when] OrderItems is empty"* - Um... No it doesn't.  If the list has zero elements than that loop is guaranteed to fail for exactly the same reason.  Why exactly does the loop *have to* be from 0-5?  Why can't you just loop over the elements which are present?  (e.g. `foreach (var item in Order.OrderItems)`)

Comment: Fact is that the `New` page doesn't crash and `OrderItems` is definitely empty there. I'm not loading it anywhere in this page. The loop is constant in order to allow me to not only edit items in the `OrderItems` collection but also to add items to it.

Comment: Just iterate out the OrderItems list, that way you can show as much as available without any conditional check.

Comment: The loop is constant in order to allow me to not only edit items in the `OrderItems` collection but also to add items to it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe you should not use a `For` loop with, let's say 5 iterations, without knowing for sure that you have to iterate 5 times. Maybe you could use a `ForEach` loop insteed or rething something in your view.

That's said, even if it is not a clean way, you can simply add a surrounding `if` statement around your inputs. Something like :

```
@for (byte i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    @if(Order.OrderItems[i] != null)
    {
        <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].OrderItemId" />
        <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Item" />
        <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Price">
    }
}
```

But again, using a `ForEach` loop would be a far better choice.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, here is what you can do :

```
@if(Order.OrderItems[i] != null)
{
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].OrderItemId" />
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Item" />
    <input asp-for="Order.OrderItems[i].Price">
}
else
{
    // new form to post the 3 inputs, allowing to reload the page with the new non null values ...
}
```

Comment: The loop is constant in order to allow me to not only edit items in the `OrderItems` collection but also to add items to it. So I can't use this solution.

Comment: The `if` part is what I have now, what I need is the `else` part... It should be bound to the `OrderItems` collection as well, so what would you put there?

Comment: @LiranFriedman That really depends on how your OrderItems list is ordered. But, if it is ordered by a unique index for instance, then you could just POST a new item to your controller, create the Object and save it in your storage (database?). Then, your front would have to reload its list in order to display what is now in the if statement. ----- I highly advise you to create your new item and then get the all list with this new item in it. You don't want to handle two states in the same time ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments it sounds like you're indicating that your model *must* have (at least) 6 elements in its list.  If that's the case then that logic belongs on the model.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    private List<OrderItem> _orderItems;
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems
    {
        get { return _orderItems; }
        set
        {
            _orderItems = value;
            if (_orderItems == null)
                _orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
            while (_orderItems.Count < 6)
                _orderItems.Add(new OrderItem());
        }
    }

    public Order()
    {
        // invoke the setter logic on object creation
        this.OrderItems = null;
    }
}
```

There are of course a variety of ways to organize the logic, this is just one example.  But the point is that if the model *must* have at least 6 elements in its list then the model is where you would guarantee that.  (Alternatively, if you feel that in your domain the *view* should be where this logic is guaranteed and the model can have other list lengths in other places that it's used, then I guess you could put the same logic on the view.  But that seems unlikely.  Logic generally belongs in models, views should just bind to those models.)

> Is there a way to overcome this error without having to manually fill in the OrderItems collection to match the loop's length?

No.  Well, depending on how you define "manually".  Do you need to write code somewhere to perform your custom logic?  Yes.  Do you need to repeat the same code everywhere that you use it?  No, that's why it belongs on the model.

Or, to put it another way: "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." -Eric Raymond